# Incorrect operation of the sequelize [Op.or]

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use [Op.or] to execute a query

```
User.findOne({
      where: { email: payload.email.trim(), '$accesses.isAccess$': 1 },
      include: [{
        model: Access,
        as: 'accesses',
        on: {
          [Op.or]: [{'$User.web_roles_id$': Sequelize.col('accesses.web_roles_id')}, {'$User.id$': Sequelize.col('accesses.web_users_id')}]
        },
        include: [{
          model: Route,
          as: 'routes'
        }]
      }]
});
```

, but it doesn't work correctly, for some reason it throws out the fields **'$User.web_roles_id$'** and **'$User.id$'** that I want to use in comparison.

That should run the following query:

> SELECT ... FROM [web_users] AS [User]  LEFT OUTER JOIN [web_access] AS
> [accesses] ON[User].[web_roles_id] = [accesses].[web_roles_id] or
> [User].[id] = [accesses].[web_users_id] LEFT OUTER JOIN [web_route] AS
> [accesses->routes] ON [accesses].[web_route_id] =
> [accesses->routes].[id]  WHERE [User].[email] = N'mail@mail.com' AND
> [accesses].[isAccess] = 1;

But it is running this instead: (fields '$User.web_roles_id$' and '$User.id$' not in operation)

> SELECT ... FROM [web_users] AS [User]  LEFT OUTER JOIN [web_access] AS
> [accesses] ON ([accesses].[web_roles_id] OR [accesses].[web_users_id])
> LEFT OUTER JOIN [web_route] AS [accesses->routes] ON
> [accesses].[web_route_id] = [accesses->routes].[id]  WHERE
> [User].[email] = N'mail@mail.com' AND [accesses].[isAccess] = 1;

My associations:

```
User.hasMany(Access, { foreignKey: "roleId", sourceKey: "roleId", as: "accesses" });
Access.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: "roleId", targetKey: "roleId", as: "user" });
Access.hasMany(Route, { foreignKey: "id", sourceKey: "routeId", as: "routes" });
Route.belongsTo(Access, { foreignKey: "id", targetKey: "routeId", as: "accesses" });
```

I would be grateful for any hints on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you try without `Op.or` and with only one of the conditions?

Comment: @Anatoly yes, if I remove Op.or, then it automatically determines the relationship between the tables, but in that case there is no second check

Comment: If you replace `Op.or` with `Op.and` will it appear in SQL correctly?

Comment: @Anatoly with `Op.and` same problem, I found in the documentation `Op.eq` and changed the request to `{ '$User.web_roles_id$': { [Op.eq]: Sequelize.col('accesses.web_roles_id') } }` it works, but it should still work without it

Comment: Weird. Good to know the workaround